# slicing an array while assigning new variables

Tags: algorithm, loops, go

I would like to create new variables based on a 10 bytes slice each time until `len(number)` is achieved. However, Go keeps giving me the following error:

> non-name variable_[i] on left side of :=

This is what I've tried so far

```
for i := 0; i < len(number); i += 10 {
        variable_[i] := number[i : i+10]
    }
```

I also tried the append and it didn't work either.

Any idea how to do this?

number is a variable so it's not a constant (it can change in size)
So I wouldn't know in advance how many new variables I want the loop to create.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do. Can you show a more complete example? This just isn't valid Go, which is why the compiler and formatter both complain.

Comment: @JimB I'm trying to slice a byte array into multiple byte arrays in order to do some arithmetic operation on each one of them separately

Comment: but the short variable declaration `variable_[i] := ...` doesn't make sense. What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: @JimB The first variable will be named variable_0, the second would be variable_10, third would be variable_20. With the variables getting the values of number according to the slice

Comment: you can't create new variable names at runtime. Just put the results in some sort of data structure, like a map with `"variable_0"` as the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go is not an interpreted language, so you cannot create a variable name and asssign some variable to it in runtime. But you may use `map` and assign new variable as its keys with appropriate values:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    variable := make(map[int][]int)

    number := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

    for i := 0; i < len(number); i += 10 {
        variable[i] = number[i : i+10]

    }
    fmt.Println(variable)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6VYM0vuBmU

Output (formatted by me for better redability):

```
map[
   0: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] 
   10:[11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
]
```

`variable[0]` and `variable[10]` are slices of 10 integers.

Comment: Have you checked the link? Source slice is split into 2 slices `variable[0]` and `variable[10]` each of 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this accomplishes your goal.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    //get some random byte data
    number := make([]byte, 27)
    rand.Read(number)
    fmt.Println("all the bytes: ", number)

    //make an output variable
    var tensOfBytes [][]byte

    //loop through number
    for i := 10; i < len(number); i += 10 {
        //get a chunk of values and store it in tensOfBytes
        tensOfBytes = append(tensOfBytes, number[i - 10 : i])
    }

    fmt.Println("bytes in 10s:")
    for _, chunk := range tensOfBytes {
        fmt.Println("\t", chunk)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BKQB7JwSHw

In general, you need to be careful of the indexes in that loop...

- if you are sure the number of bytes is a multiple of 10, you're good to go.
- `i` increases by 10 each iteration of the loop, be careful using it as an index for another variable..
- probably other edge cases..